# Within rows multiplication Excel

Tags: excel, multiplication

I am in need of some help with multiplication in Excel. What I want to do is to multiply all the values in the cells of one column with the values of cells in another column.

Say I have a column A and a column B. In the cells A1...An of column A there are some values. Now I want the values of A1...An to be multiplied with the values I input in B1...Bn. In particular, I want what I input in A1 to be multiplied by what I input in B1, what I input in A2 by what I input in B2 and so on and so forth.

In the cell A1 I have the value ‘1’, say. In the cell A2 I have the value ‘2’. In the cells with which I want to multiply these values (cells B1 and B2) I have the formulae =0,4*A1 and =0,7*A2 (0,4 and 0,7 are just variables). Essentially, 1 and 2 are the amounts I have of an item, the price of which I have in the B cells (0,4 and 0,7). So I am multiplying the amount of an item with its price.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is hard for me to make sense of what you've written, but to help us help you, I suggest you familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Some things that might help.  type out 3-4 rows/columns of sample data with expected results.  What is x?  what is cell?  your third paragraph is currently very confusing.

Comment: Are you aware that when you type a formula in C1 like `=A1*B1` and then you copy the cell and paste in the cell or cells below that the 1 will automatically change by 1 for each row the destination (pasted) cell is below from where you copied it from?  If you place a $ in from of the letter or the number it will keep that part of the cell address from changing in the formula as its copied?

Comment: I edited the question a bit, hoping to make it easier to understand. I'm not sure that you answer is an answer to my question, Forward Ed. That is undoubtedly because of my clumsiness in formulating the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you spend a lot of time explaining your data, you don't really explain what you want very well. It sounds to me like you want to multiply values in Column A with values in Column B and then ADD all of those results up. If this is true, then a sumproduct formula is what you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:An*B1:Bn)
```

This will multiply each column, row by row, and add the results of those multiplications together.

Answer (score 0):

From your question. this is what I was thinking?

```
=A1*(0.4*A1)
=A2*(0.7*A2)
```